# Yii2 kartik Form Builder + INPUT_WIDGET + NumberControl

Tags: yii2, widget, builder, kartik-v

I want to use widget NumberControl in kartik's Form Bulder. But when I try this code, i have an empty form and there no errors. Couse I can't understand where is my mistake.

Please tell me if someone use a NumberControl in kartik's Form Builder.

```
use kartik\builder\Form;
echo Form::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'form' => $form,
        'columns' => 6,
        'columnSize' => 'md',
        'attributes' => [
          'oi_count' => [
                'type' => Form::INPUT_WIDGET,
                'widgetClass' => '\kartik\number\NumberControl',
                ],
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this:https://demosbs3.krajee.com/number by default the type is "hidden", you should set it to "text".

Comment: Great find and answer! Can you add a working solution of OPs example code with the fix? Thanks!